Low Resolution on Third Party Apps
I had posted another question but that was not as elaborate.
I'm new to Ubuntu, previously a windows user. The problem I'm having in with ubuntu is that the applications(chrome, vs code) that I'm using have the resolution 1280x720. While the ubuntu native is 1920x1080. In the display settings resolution is set to 1920x1080.
Here is the output of xrandr
    Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 1280 x 720, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP-1 connected primary 1280x720+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 280mm x 160mm
   1280x720      59.86*+
   800x600       59.86  
   640x480       59.38  
   320x240       59.52  
   1152x720      59.97  
   960x600       59.96  
   928x580       59.88  
   800x500       59.50  
   768x480       59.90  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x400       59.95  
   320x200       58.96  
   1024x576      59.90  
   864x486       59.92  
   720x400       59.55  
   640x350       59.77

here is the output of sudo lshw -c display
*-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: HD Graphics 5500
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 resolution=1920,1080
       resources: irq:54 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff

